# SharedPreferences remain intact between app upgrades?

Tags: android

I'm using SharedPreferences to store some app settings. If I push a new version to marketplace, and my users download, will all those SharedPreferences be removed on the upgrade? I know my sqlite databases will remain intact, wondering if the same is true for SharedPreferences.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your SharedPreferences will upgrade between versions.  They are just files in your package's data directory (`/data/data/<your_package>/shared_prefs/`), all of which are retained during upgrades.

Comment: Ok sounds good, yeah I saw them in DDMS, so as long as they stay in place between upgrades I'm set, thanks.