# Does android clear/remove all user preference during upgrade?

Tags: android

Can you please does android clear/remove all user preference during upgrade?

1. upgrade my apk from market
2. upgrade my apk from command line 'adb install'
3. upgrade my apk by clicking a link contains the apk
4. upgrade when I debug it via eclipse

Comment: only if you uninstall first, then reinstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using SharedPreferences? If so:

Your SharedPreferences will upgrade between versions. They will not be deleted. They are just files in your package's data directory (`/data/data/<your_package>/shared_prefs/`), all of which are retained during upgrades.

Credits to [Daniel Lew in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894131/sharedpreferences-remain-intact-between-app-upgrades)

Answer (score 1):

No. Upgrade retains user preferences.